# App Engine Node flexible instance constantly running

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, firebase-queue

I have several [Firebase-Queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) NodeJS instances running in my project on App Engine.

The instances seems to be constantly running, producing errors after trying a GET request.

```
13:33:36.078
{"method":"GET","latencySeconds":"0.000","referer":"-","host":"-","user":"-","code":"502","remote":"130.211.0.96","agent":"GoogleHC/1.0","path":"/_ah/health","size":"166"}
13:33:36.421
{"method":"GET","latencySeconds":"0.000","referer":"-","host":"-","user":"-","code":"502","remote":"130.211.1.229","agent":"GoogleHC/1.0","path":"/_ah/health","size":"166"}

13:33:37.000
[error] 32#0: *80631 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 130.211.1.11, server: , request: "GET /_ah/health HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:8080/_ah/health", host: "10.128.0.5"
13:33:37.000
[error] 32#0: *80633 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 130.211.3.85, server: , request: "GET /_ah/health HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:8080/_ah/health", host: "10.128.0.5"
```

My App.yaml file when i deploy my Node apps looks like this:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: album-queue
skip_files:
- ^(node_modules)

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: build/index.js
```

I think it must have something to do with all these these GET requests it's trying to do internally, but I don't know how to stop them / fix it. My bills are raking up fairly quickly, so would be pretty nice to get it fixed >_<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine Flex [doesn't scale to zero](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users#scaling_characteristics) like the standard environment does. There will always be at least one instance running (default is actually 2).  The requests you see are the [normal health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-instances-are-managed#health_checking).